# Apache Solr post.jar issue

Tags: solr

I am new to Apache Solr. I am going by the following tutorial -*https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-solr/apache-solr-tutorial-beginners/*

While I am able to index my books.csv on my local machine, but I am getting following issue on my virtual machine- [Unable to access jarfile post.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHsAX.png)

I am using Solr 6.3.0 and java 1.8

Please help !!

Answer (score 1):

Your java command is not able to find `post.jar` in bin directory.

by default `post.jar` is present in `{solr_home}\example\exampledocs` directory of solr

you can try giving following path for `post.jar`

```
-jar ../example/exampledocs/post.jar
```

Complete command as per your directory structure.

```
solr-6.0.0\bin>java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/jcg/update -jar ../example/exampledocs/post.jar books.csv
```

Comment: My post.jar is in exampledocs. I did what you asked for. I am still facing few issues. Could you let me have the exact command to hit ? Solr exampledocs location is _F:\kk\Solr Installation\solr-6.3\solr-6.3.0\example\exampledocs_               and command I am hitting is _F:\kk\Solr Installation\solr-6.3\solr-6.3.0\bin>java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http:
//localhost:8983/solr/jcg/update -jar F:/kk/Solr Installation/solr-6.3/solr-6.3.0/example/exampledocs/post.jar  books.csv_

Comment: Thank you so much !! But Now I am facing the following-- `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/so
lr/util/SimplePostTool : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Java version mismatch. Execute using JRE 8

Comment: there could be multiple versions of java installed in your machine. type following command in terminal and make sure it is JRE 8.  "java -version"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is an issue reading the path of the post.jar file.
In the tutorial it says the command is:  `java -jar /exampledocs/post.jar /films/films.xml`

Instead,
Give the full path:
`java -jar C:\Program Files\solr-8.6.1\example\films\post.jar films.xml`
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Try to add the path of post.jar to your solrconfig.xml file** so that the core or collection can know where it is present.